# How to add suffix to label in a row chart using dc.js?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

In a row chart it is showing only label I  want suffix as "%" along with label value using dc.js how to do that?

Comment: [.label(d => d.value + '%')](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BaseMixin.html#label__anchor) ?